# that-clause following "make sure"

Tags: clauses, error

The following is an excerpt from CNN. Ameera is a character in a puppet show. I'm wondering how the that-clause following the dash connects to the preceding text.

> “Ameera is a really fun and cool girl,” said Deborah Marie Rodríguez García, education manager of humanitarian programs at Sesame Workshop. “She loves sports, and she loves science, technology, engineering and math. We wanted to **make sure that that is represented as well ─ that girls can go against the gender stereotypes and biases.**”

Is the author trying to say, "We wanted to make sure that girls can go against the gender stereotypes and biases"?

Another possibility in my mind is the author meant to use "this instead of 'that" before "is represented as well." Is the following the intended message?

> “Ameera is a really fun and cool girl,” said Deborah Marie Rodríguez García, education manager of humanitarian programs at Sesame Workshop. “She loves sports, and she loves science, technology, engineering and math. We wanted to **make sure that *this* is represented as well ─ that girls can go against the gender stereotypes and biases.**”

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is intended to have "that that", "make sure that" is one part, "that is represented as well" is another part. But yes you are *also* right to say that you *can* switch it with a "this", which is one of the ways to deal with double "that", as it can be confusing and repetitive to some.

The first "that" is just something that goes along with "make sure", and the second "that" refers to "that girls can go against the gender stereotypes and biases"

But "We wanted to make sure that this is represented as well ─ that girls can go against the gender stereotypes and biases.", can sound a bit off, so maybe use the below

> We wanted to make sure that girls **going** against gender stereotypes and biases is represented as well

Comment: I highly suspect the speaker meant to say, " We wanted to make sure that **the belief** is represented as well ─ that girls can go against the gender stereotypes and biases.”"

Comment: But that is close to what I was trying to say (hopefully?) @Apollyon

Comment: The original cannot be made sense of in terms of grammar.

Comment: Ah so I'm wrong I guess? @Apollyon

Comment: I am not sure. The passage is spoken, so the speaker might have been speaking in a sloppy manner.